# How to get the facebook video details using facebook graphApi in android

Tags: android, facebook, video

I want to get the details of the video by using the URL. I am getting for the videos if Url like this https://www.facebook.com/pus18/videos/498575787191356/.
 below is my code for getting the video details

```
      request_fb_video = new GraphRequest(
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        "/498575787191356/",
                        null,
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.e("response", "res...." + response.toString());

                            }
                        }
                );
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,source,picture");
                request_fb_video.setParameters(parameters);
                request_fb_video.executeAsync();
```

I want to get video details from the below Url.Please help me to resolve this issue.

https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1154564254673489&id=100003597778317

Comment: You’d need to parse this URL, so that you can assemble the necessary identifier in the form `userid_postid` from it. Then you can request the details for this post via API (provided the user has granted your app permission to read their posts.)

Comment: I tried to like this userid_postid but it is not working

Comment: Of course it works, that https://www.facebook.com/100003597778317_1154564254673489 redirects to the post proves it. If you want to request data for that post via API, you of course, as already mentioned, need to get the user’s permission first.